# Deleted record in React-admin shows in the list using custom data provider

Tags: react-admin

I have a custom data provider implementing delete method this way:

```
delete: (resource, { id, previousData }) => {
  return deleteRecord(id).then(res => {
    if (res.data.deleteRecord.success) {
      return { data: previousData };
    }
  });
},
```

The deleteRecord function successfully calls to apollo-client and delete the distant data.

React-admin redirects to the list and shows the notification with "undo" button.

When this notification disappears, the delete record shows back in the list.

I have to refresh the window in order to see the expected data, react-admin refresh also shows the wrong data.

This issue also happens with deleteMany directly from the List component.

Here is my implementation of the method, which works fine as well.

```
deleteMany: (resource, { ids }) => {
      return Promise.all(
        ids.map(id => {
          return deleteRecord(id).then(res => {
            if (res.data.deleteRecord.success) {
              return id;
            }
          });
        })
      ).then(data => ({ data }));
    },
```

I expect the local state of the list to align with successfully called delete function in the dataProvider.

I already tried different mutationOptions, custom appBar, custom onSuccess and afterDelete lifecycle but none of them seem to be where the issue happens.